# Events organized vertically in Week view and horizentally in Month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

After playing around with fullcalendar for a large project, i figured out that fullCal sorts events vertically in Week view (check the bottom view of the attached image) and horizontally in Month view (attached image top).

They are all supposed to be sorted horizontally in week view as well.
How can we get them sorted horizontally in week view as well ?

Thanks

[image: Events organized vertically in Week view and horizentally in Month view]

Comment: Hang on, what is your question? It looks like it's working okay to me from the screenshots you've provided.

Comment: You made a statement that they are all supposed to be horizontal. I assume this is supposed to be a question. The screen shots you show are accurate shots of what they are supposed to look like

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear enough .... edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them all to be horizontal than use the basicWeek view not the agendaWeek view